# Determine the Image of a certain Conformal function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider mapping : $$f(z)=\int_0^z \displaystyle \frac{\sqrt[5](1-\xi^5)^2} {\sqrt[5](1+\xi^5)^2}d \xi$$please find out the shape of $f(\mathbb{D})$,and give proper reasons.

Comment: Should there be any $\xi$ in the integrand?

Comment: Same question as Arthur : Isn't it $$f(z)=\int_0^z \displaystyle \frac{\sqrt[5]{1-\xi^5}^2} {\sqrt[5]{1+\xi^5}^2}d \xi$$ ?

Comment: The fifth roots of $-1$ (poles of the denominator) should play a rôle, probably generate an angle (don't you think ?) in the image of $\mathbb{D}$ (please confirm that it is the unit disk)

Comment: The 2 is under sqrt but I don’t know how to extend the sqrt line to make it happen.

Comment: This reminds me of the [Schwarz–Christoffel transformation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping), possible composed with a rational function.